# Jmeter Dashboard report - Sampler count does not match to individual lines

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner

JMeter Dashboard Report has an anomaly under the "Statistics" table where the total samples do not match the individual lines if added up.
Have you ever encountered this behavior before? What is your impression about what might be going on?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of [Filtering applied](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#saveservice_requirements)

Here is an example of [generating dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report) from the same [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) without and with filter.

[image]

so I would recommend to check:

1. Your JMeter command line
2. jmeter.properties file
3. user.properties file

for any occurrence of `jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter` property, once you remove it - the sample results count should match

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Reporting configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)